errores de etapas en C#
resulta que tengo armado un codigo que hice en C# (visual studio) sobre un juego, de una nave espacial, estudio tecnicatura en desarrollo de videojuegos, hay cosas casi listas que tengo del codigo, pero tengo un problema
resulta que yo estoy usando para este juego una variable llamada "etapaJuego" que sirve para las etapas de este dependiendo de las acciones que haga, primera etapa, el menu, segunda etapa, el nivel, tercera etapa, una imagen de victoria, y esta solo aparece cuando se hayan eliminado todas las naves enemigas, el problema es que yo cuando inicio el juego sin depurar, aparece el menu, pero al darle click, no sucede nada de nada, el menu sigue igual, pero su musica se detiene con hacer el click pero de ahi, el nivel no aparece, aca dejare el codigo entero que hice, en una clase llamada "programs" no se que ando haciendo mal o que estoy tocando, espero que puedan darme una mano, muchas gracias
using System;
using Tao.Sdl;

public struct GameObject
{
    public int positionX;
    public int positionY;
    public int speed;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public int health;
    public nave_test.Image image;
    public bool isActive;
}

namespace nave_test
{
    class Program
    {

        static bool isMenuActive = true; 
        static bool isVictory = false;
        static Image menuImage; 
        static Image victoryImage; 

        static Image background;
        static Image imageplayer; 
        static Image imageenemy;

        static Sound sound;

        static int ammo = 50;
        static int etapaJuego;

        static GameObject NAVE;
        static GameObject[] ENEMIGA = new GameObject[10];
        static GameObject[] bullets = new GameObject[10];

        static DateTime timeLastShoot;
        static int fireRate = 1;


        static void InitializeGameObjects()
        {

            NAVE.positionX = 300;
            NAVE.positionY = 400;
            NAVE.speed = 8;
            NAVE.width = 100;
            NAVE.height = 100;
            NAVE.image = Engine.LoadImage("assets/NAVE JUGABLE.png");
            NAVE.isActive = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < ENEMIGA.Length; i++)
            {
                ENEMIGA[i].speed = 5;
                ENEMIGA[i].width = 60;
                ENEMIGA[i].health = 2;
                ENEMIGA[i].height = 100;
                ENEMIGA[i].image = Engine.LoadImage("assets/NAVE ENEMIGA.png");
                ENEMIGA[i].isActive = true;
            }

            ENEMIGA[0].positionX = 0;


            ENEMIGA[0].positionX = 100;
            ENEMIGA[1].positionX = 200;
            ENEMIGA[2].positionX = 400;
            ENEMIGA[3].positionX = 600;
            ENEMIGA[4].positionX = 800;


            ENEMIGA[5].positionX = 100;
            ENEMIGA[6].positionX = 200;
            ENEMIGA[7].positionX = 400;
            ENEMIGA[8].positionX = 600;
            ENEMIGA[9].positionX = 800;

            ENEMIGA[0].positionY = 0;
            ENEMIGA[1].positionY = 0;
            ENEMIGA[2].positionY = 0;
            ENEMIGA[3].positionY = 0;
            ENEMIGA[4].positionY = 0;

            ENEMIGA[5].positionY = 200;
            ENEMIGA[6].positionY = 200;
            ENEMIGA[7].positionY = 200;
            ENEMIGA[8].positionY = 200;
            ENEMIGA[9].positionY = 200;

            for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Length; i++)
            {
                bullets[i].speed = 20;
                bullets[i].width = 20;
                bullets[i].height = 15;
                bullets[i].image = Engine.LoadImage("assets/bullet.png");
                bullets[i].isActive = false;
            }
             


        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Engine.Initialize();
            InitializeGameObjects();

            etapaJuego = 1;
         
            menuImage = Engine.LoadImage("assets/MENU.png"); 

            background = Engine.LoadImage("assets/FONDO.png");
            
            imageenemy = Engine.LoadImage("assets/NAVE ENEMIGA.png");

            victoryImage = Engine.LoadImage("assets/VICTORY.png");

            Sound.PlayMenuMusic();

            while (true)
            {
                CheckInputs();
                Update();
                Render();
                Sdl.SDL_Delay(20);
            }
        }


        static void CheckInputs()
        {

            Sdl.SDL_PumpEvents();

            if (isMenuActive)
            {
          
                if (Engine.MouseClick())
                {
                    Sound.StopMusic();
                    isMenuActive = false; 
                }
            }
            else


            if (Engine.KeyPress(Engine.KEY_A)) 
            {
                if (NAVE.positionX > 0)
                    NAVE.positionX -= NAVE.speed;
            }
            if (Engine.KeyPress(Engine.KEY_S)) 
            {
                if (NAVE.positionY + NAVE.width < Engine.alto)
                    NAVE.positionY += NAVE.speed;
            }
            if (Engine.KeyPress(Engine.KEY_W)) 
            {
                if (NAVE.positionY > 0)
                    NAVE.positionY -= NAVE.speed;
            }
            if (Engine.KeyPress(Engine.KEY_D)) 
            {
                if (NAVE.positionX + NAVE.height < Engine.ancho)
                    NAVE.positionX += NAVE.speed;
            }

            if (Engine.KeyPress(Engine.KEY_V))
            {
                if (ammo > 0)
                {
                    if ((DateTime.Now - timeLastShoot).TotalSeconds > fireRate)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (bullets[i].isActive == false)
                            {
                                bullets[i].isActive = true;
                                bullets[i].positionX = NAVE.positionX + NAVE.width / 2;
                                bullets[i].positionY = NAVE.positionY;
                                ammo--;
                                timeLastShoot = DateTime.Now;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (Engine.KeyPress(Engine.KEY_ESC))
            {
                        Environment.Exit(0);
            }
                
        }

        
        static void Update()
        {
            bool allEnemiesDestroyed = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < ENEMIGA.Length; i++)
            {
                if (ENEMIGA[i].isActive)
                {
                    allEnemiesDestroyed = false;
                    break; 
                }
            }

            if (allEnemiesDestroyed)
            {
                etapaJuego = 3; 
            }



            for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Length; i++)
            {
                if (bullets[i].isActive)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < ENEMIGA.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (ENEMIGA[j].isActive && checkCollision(bullets[i], ENEMIGA[j]))
                        {
                            bullets[i].isActive = false;
                            ENEMIGA[j].health--;


                            if (ENEMIGA[j].health <= 0)
                            {
                                ENEMIGA[j].isActive = false;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < ENEMIGA.Length; i++) 
            {

            ENEMIGA[i].positionX += ENEMIGA[i].speed;

            if (ENEMIGA[i].positionX >= 761 - 60 || ENEMIGA[i].positionX <= 0)
            {
                ENEMIGA[i].speed = ENEMIGA[i].speed * -1;
            }
          }
            for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Length; i++)
            {
                if (bullets[i].isActive)
                {

                    bullets[i].positionY -= bullets[i].speed;
                }
                if (bullets[i].positionY < 0)
                {
                    bullets[i].isActive = false;
                }
            }
        }

        static void Render()
        {
          
            Engine.Show();
            if (isMenuActive)
            {
                Engine.Clear();
               
                int x = (Engine.ancho - menuImage.Width) / 2;
                int y = (Engine.alto - menuImage.Height) / 2;
                Engine.Draw(menuImage, 0, 0);
            }
            else if (etapaJuego == 2)
            {
               
                Engine.Draw(background, 0, 0);


               for (int i = 0; i < ENEMIGA.Length; i++)
               {
                    if (ENEMIGA[i].isActive)
                    {
                     Engine.Draw(ENEMIGA[i].image, ENEMIGA[i].positionX, ENEMIGA[i].positionY);
                    }
                
               }

                for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (bullets[i].isActive)
                    {
                      Engine.Draw(bullets[i].image, bullets[i].positionX, bullets[i].positionY);
                    }
                    
                }


                Engine.Draw(NAVE.image, NAVE.positionX, NAVE.positionY);
                
             }
            else if (etapaJuego == 3)  
            {
                Engine.Clear();
                int x = (Engine.ancho - victoryImage.Width) / 2;
                int y = (Engine.alto - victoryImage.Height) / 2;
                Engine.Draw(victoryImage, x, y);
            }


            Sdl.SDL_Delay(10);

      }
    
        static bool checkCollision(GameObject a, GameObject b)
        {
            if ((a.positionX < b.positionX + b.width) && (a.positionX + a.width > b.positionX) && (a.positionY < b.positionY + b.height) && a.positionY + a.height > b.positionY)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

